# Compile BlueZ on ubuntu: configure error

Tags: ubuntu, bluez

I tried to compile bluez for ubuntu 18.04 downloading the latest version (5.50) from [here](http://www.bluez.org/release-of-bluez-5-50/).

`configure` command:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-mesh
```

Fails with the message:

```
...
checking for ELL... no
configure: error: ell library >= 0.3 is required
```

I ignore what is ELL and why it is used (nice to know), but the true question is about the missing dependencies to install for getting rid off this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to install the Embedded Linux Library.

[Embedded Linux Library](https://01.org/ell)

Might be the Microsoft Embedded Learning Library, but not as likely.

[Microsoft/ELL](https://github.com/Microsoft/ELL/blob/master/INSTALL-Ubuntu.md)

Comment: Many thanks, downloaded from [Embedded Linux Library](https://01.org/ell) and compiled from sources.

Answer (score 3):

If you come here one reason should be that you need bluez with mesh protocol enabled.

This is the recipe that works for me on ubuntu 18.04 and bluez 5.50.

### Build and install ELL

I did not find a packaged release of ELL, so I downloaded the latest ELL release from [here](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/ell/).

```
> tar xvf ~/Downloads/ell-0.6.tar.gz
> cd ell-0.6
> ./configure --prefix=/usr
> make
> sudo make install
```

### Build and install Bluez

bluez may be downloaded from [here](http://www.bluez.org/).

```
> tar xvf ~/Downloads/bluez-5.50.tar.xz
> cd bluez-5.50
# install required dependencies
> sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev libjson-c-dev
> ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-mesh --enable-deprecated
> make
> sudo make install
```

NOTE 1: Use `--enable-deprecated` if you need `hcitool` because it is deprecated in recente bluez versions.

NOTE 2: Before running `meshctl` make sure `bluetooth` service is running:

```
> systemctl status bluetooth

# if not running:
> systemctl start bluetooth

# if start fails with
# Failed to start bluetooth.service: Unit bluetooth.service is masked.
> systemctl unmask bluetooth
```